# How could I use linq when calculating a answer from a symbol and two numbers

Tags: c#, linq

Recently I had an interview which asked to write a method to calculate the answer from a prefix formatted string.

The feedback from the interview was that I should have used Linq

I am a bit confused where I should have used linq and was wondering if anyone could help me.

**The Problem**

The signature method should be:

```
int Calculate(string expression)
```

I didn't need to validate the input but was given some examples of

- "+ 3 4" should give 7
- "- 2 10" should give -8
- "* 10 -20" should give -200
- "/ 6 2" should give 3

**My Solution - from memory**

So I created unit tests and developed the code in a TDD manor

```
[TestFixture]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Test]
    public void TestMethod_Add()
    {
        var calculator = new Calculator();
        var result = calculator.Calculate("+ 4 2");
        var expected = 6;

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestMethod_Sub()
    {
        var calculator = new Calculator();
        var result = calculator.Calculate("- 2 10");
        var expected = -8;

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestMethod1_mult()
    {

        var calculator = new Calculator();
        var result = calculator.Calculate("* 10 -20");
        var expected = -200;

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestMethod1_div()
    {
        var calculator = new Calculator();
        var result = calculator.Calculate("/ 6 2");
        var expected = 3;

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
    }
```

and created the follow code something like this:

```
public class Calculator
{
    public int Calculate(string expression)
    {
        var tokens = expression.Split(' ');

        var symbol = tokens[0];
        var num1 = int.Parse(tokens[1]);
        var num2 = int.Parse(tokens[2]);

        switch (symbol)
        {
            case "+":
                return num1 + num2;

            case "-":
                return num1 - num2;

            case "*":
                return num1 * num2;

            case "/":
                return num1 / num2;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException("Symbol has not been implemented");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Use Linq? I can´t see any advantage or any need to do this. You could of course use something like `symbol = tokens.First()`, however I doubt this is what they wanted you to do.

Comment: linq is awesome and everything, but to say "you should have used LINQ" is a bit daft. I think you dodged a bullet, my man...

Comment: Your answer is fine. Did they say that you have to find a LINQ approach before you started? Also, have they said that more than two numbers are possible?

Comment: There is no reasonable way to "use LINQ" here other than in contrived ways which don't add anything to the solution. The only thing I can remotely think of is using `Enumerable.Aggregate` on the argument list after the operator has been determined, but while that's one approach, it's certainly not one that immediately springs to mind, and rejecting alternatives for not using it is silly. Did they give you any details about the solution they had in mind?

Comment: Maybe [Dynamic LINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Library)?

Comment: I agree that I would not use LINQ to solve this problem. Given that validation was explicitly not a part of the problem, I think your code looks fine. The only nit I would note is that the default case should not throw NotImplemented; that exception implies that the input was correct, its just that you haven't gotten around to implementing the feature yet. But you've implemented every feature you were asked to, so there's no unimplemented feature here. This should really be an invalid argument exception; you've managed to write some validation logic after all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is as much LINQ as I can stuff into it:

```
int Calculate(string expression) {
    var operations = new Dictionary<char, Func<int, int, int>> {
        { '+', (a, b) => a + b },
        { '-', (a, b) => a - b },
        { '*', (a, b) => a * b },
        { '/', (a, b) => a / b },
    };
    return expression
        .Substring(2)
        .Split(' ')
        .Select(o => int.Parse(o))
        .Aggregate(operations[expression[0]])
    ;
}
```

As an added bonus, this can effortlessly handle such expressions as `"* 1 2 3 4 5"` (5!, which as we all know is 120) or `"/ 1729 7 13 19"` (in case you like to do your factoring in reverse).

This is half in jest. I would *not* consider this an appropriate implementation in production for a `Calculate` method that explicitly has to handle only two values. If your interviewer was just looking for how clever you could make something, though, this could have scored you points. (And if they were just looking for how clever you could make something for a trivial problem, be glad you didn't get the job -- maintenance at that company could be a bad thing.)

(Note to self: figure out some really neat way to split the string using `SelectMany` somehow.)

Comment: Nice one, doubt that one can more 'LINQify' it that it is in this example.

Comment: Nice. A very LINQy answer. I would still say that mine is more readable though. I'm going to mark yours as the answer though as it's the most LINQy which is what the question was. Thanks everyone

Comment: @BrownCow: You're absolutely right, your code is more readable and I would be much more happy encountering it in production myself (since it's instantly obvious what it does and what it doesn't do, which can't be said for my code). You don't need to feel bad for "flunking" this particular interview.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe they wanted to see something like this (but I like your answer ;-) )

```
int Calculate(string expression)
    {
        char symbol = expression.First();
        int[] numbers = Array.ConvertAll(expression.Substring(2).Split(' '), p => int.Parse(p)); 

        switch (symbol)
        {
            case '+':
                return numbers.Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);
            case '-':
                return numbers.Aggregate((a, b) => a - b);
            case '*':
                return numbers.Aggregate((a, b) => a * b);
            case '/':
                return numbers.Aggregate((a, b) => a / b);
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not LINQy enough. Make sure you use a `Func<int, int, int>` delegate for the operation, so only one single call to `Aggregate` remains.

Comment: Still not? Damnit ;-)

Comment: You also have to parse the string and you should avoid `var` on simple types ;-)

Comment: @TimSchmelter You are right. Added your suggestions ;-)

Comment: Thanks @schlonzo this is probably looking more like they expected but I don't understand why it is better. I like clean code to help keep things more maintainable. My code was obvious what it was doing and your code still has to do a switch with the operators for each case. I think their comment was that to reduce duplication I should have used linq. Thanks for the solution it was starting annoy me here I had gone wrong. After all my tests all passed 